# My Complex Dictionary is Jumbling up

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, cherrypy

Question:
I am trying to make the wanted result from the provided XML. In the attempted code all the dictionaries jumble up and in the bar key I get ipsum values.

**Wanted Result:**

```
{'bar': [{'a': 'foo', 'b': 'bar', 'c': 'bazz', 'd': 'boo', 'e': 'bing'}, {'a': 'foo', 'b': 'bar', 'c': 'bazz', 'd': 'boo'}], 'ipsum': {'a': 'lorem', 'b': 'ipsum', 'c': 'dolar', 'd': 'sit', 'e': 'amet'}, {'a': 'lorem', 'b': 'ipsum', 'c': 'dolor', 'd': 'sit'}
```

Extra details: Yes i want to remove the None value of foobar for the first part of the list in the dictionaries value. Yes the second part of of the dictionaries is foobar

**Attempted Code:**

```
data = {}
toplevel = {}
secondlevel = {}
details = []

for alphabet in root.findall("*[@type='3']"):
    toplevel.clear()
    secondevel.clear()

    for i in alphabet:
        toplevel.update({i.tag: i.text})
        toplevel = {k: v for k, v in toplevel.items() if v} #Remove Keys if the value equals None or "          /n" (Doesn't work)

    for foobar in toplevel.find("foobar"):
        secondlevel.update({foobar.tag: foobar.text})
        continue


    details.append(toplevel, secondlevel])

    data.update({alphabet.find("b").text: details})
```

**XML**:

```
<lorem>
    <foo type="3">
        <a>foo</a>
        <b>bar</b>
        <c>bazz</c>
        <d>boo</d>
        <e>bing</e>

        <foobar>
            <a>foo</a>
            <b>bar</b>
            <c>bazz</c>
            <d>boo</d>
        <foobar>
    </foo>

    <foo type="3">
        <a>lorem</a>
        <b>ipsum</b>
        <c>dolor</c>
        <d>sit/d>
        <e>amet</e>

        <foobar>
            <a>lorem</a>
            <b>ipsum</b>
            <c>dolor</c>
            <d>sit</d>
        <foobar>
    </foo>
</lorem>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the PicklingTools XML to dict converter could give you exactly 
what you want.

See: [XML to dict translation doc](http://www.picklingtools.com/html/xmldoc.html)

You might have to futz with the flags to get exactly what you want, (I think you would want to drop the attributes so you don't pick up "type" as a key).
Maybe use XML_LOAD_DROP_ALL_ATTRS

You'd want something like this to process the XML file

```
<top>
  <a>1</a>
  <b>2.2</b>
  <c>three</c>
</top>
```

and turn it into a dictionary:

```
>>> from xmlloader import *
>>> example = file('example.xml', 'r')
>>> xl = StreamXMLLoader(example, 0)  # 0 = All defaults on options
>>> result = xl.expectXML()
>>> print result
{'top': {'a': '1', 'c': 'three', 'b': '2.2'}}
```

There are two versions of the code: a pure Python version and a C extension module.  The second is if you need the raw speed of C for converting from large XML files.